# How does using add() to one ArrayList interfere the size of the other one?

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I created two ArrayList and I want to add some Integers to ArrayList a.
In Java code I did this:

```
ArrayList < Integer > a = new ArrayList < Integer >();
ArrayList b = a;
a.add(new Integer(4));
b.add(new Integer(5));
a.add(new Integer(6));
a.add(new Integer(7));
System.out.println(a.size());
```

My quesiton is why does `b.add(new Integer(5));`also add one object to ArrayList a?

Comment: do you know what `ArrayList b = a` do?

Comment: I'm a java newbie and I really don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following image where the illustration is given with Date objects. A variable declaration such as `ArrayList<Integer> a` creates a reference which is then assigned the adress of the object created by the right part of the statement `new ArrayList < Integer >();`with the help of the assignment operator `=`

Now when you declare `ArrayList b=a`your are stating that the 2nd reference called b is assigned the same adress as the first reference a. Therefore a and b both refer to the same object in memory

[image: two variable referencing the same object]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object.
You are confusing primitive values with object references. When you run something like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a = 15;
System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
```

The output will be:

```
a = 15
b = 10;
```

When you use a primitive (int, String, long, byte, double, boolean, short...), you are COPYING the value of that variable into another, like in the example above. `b` looks at the value of `a`, and assigns it to `b` creating two separate variables.

What you did with ArrayLists, on the other hand, since they are OBJECTS, both `a` and `b` are pointing to the same thing. If you want to create separate objects, you would need to do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then you would get the results you want.

Hope this helps. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList b = a;
```

From here both a and b point the `same memory`. So both the objects having same values.

Answer (score 2):

`a = new ArrayList<>();` **a** points to an object (an ArrayList instance) at memory address 0x1234 (the address is made up).

`b = a;` **b** points to the same address as **a** points to.

So every operation on **a** or **b** affects the same object in memory. Hence `b.add(new Integer(5))` has the same result as `a.add(new Integer(5))`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList b is a reference to ArrayList a. There is really only one list with two pointers to it.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist b is referencing arraylist a. If you want the split, look up java's clone() method.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass value of a to b. You actually the pass the value of the reference to the object. which means that a and b are pointing to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining the code as is:

```
ArrayList b = a;
```

on this line you create a variable able to hold an ArrayList, and you make this `b` variable you just created point at `a` which is another variable able to hold an ArrayList.

`a` points on an Arraylist object (the new ArrayList you created on line one).

This does **not** mean that after line two you have two ArrayLists. There only exist **one** ArrayList object and **two** variables that point to the memory this object is stored.

So by calling the add method on any of the variables `a` or `b` you add on the same ArrayList.